# Create Layout for Music Player in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to create my Music Player in android.

I am Learning all the things and my design is quite poor.

So to create a Music Player in android i want to create layout like following images.

[image]

As we can see images of all the songs are displayed in back.

I am very confused that how can i create such layout in android?

Please help me to understand how i can create such different Layout?

As i specified i am having no knowledge of designing i always done back-end code.

Please tell me how such different Layout designs can be carried out in android?

What i want to do is i want to display all the songs images and allow user to select song by selecting images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at staggered Grid View :

https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid

https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView

That should help you with the background of all images for songs. Next you want that list and player and one main photo on top of the layout when the user selects a particular song, you can use frame layouts, so that it will shown on top of the Grid View.